# What is this SQL code doing?

Tags: sql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE DAG(
  firstID NUMBER,
  secondID NUMBER,
);
```

What is this code doing?

Comment: Your data is not a DAG (yes it is, but it is degenerated into a tree) It is just a tree.

Comment: Forgive me if this a stupid question, but where is the code referred to by "What is this code doing?" Or is it referring to the snippet above? If yes, may I know which RDBMS it is specific to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's finding all the direct and indirect descendants of each ancestor.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7beb/3).

Share and enjoy.